# How update / delete google contacts api v3? in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm programming the Google APIs in PHP. The Contacts API v3. I can create contacts but I can not edit them and delete them.

**This is the data I get. For example:**

Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Sergio[email] => sergioales@yahoo.com [id] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/email%40gmail.com/base/4205b6d80df6ed10 [etag] => "RX0zfDVSLyt7I2A9XBJXFk4NQgw." ) );

```
$XML='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008"
xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch"><entry gd:etag="'.$etag.'">
    <batch:id>update</batch:id>
    <batch:operation type="update"/>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2008#contact"/>
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/email%40gmail.com/base/4205b6d80df6ed10</id>
    <updated>'.date("Y-m-d").'T'.date("H:i").':00.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
      term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
    <title type="text">'.$name.'</title>
    <gd:name>
      <gd:givenName>'.$name.'</gd:givenName>
      <gd:familyName></gd:familyName>
      <gd:fullName>'.$name.'</gd:fullName>
    </gd:name>
    <content type="text">Actualizado el '.date("d-m-Y H:i").' </content>
    <gd:email address="' . $email. '" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"/>
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile" primary="true">25151515151</gd:phoneNumber>
    </entry></feed>';
```

And use curl

```
$headers = array('Host: www.google.com',
  'Gdata-version: 3.0',
  'Content-type: application/atom+xml',
  'If-Match: *',
  'Authorization: OAuth ' . $access_token);
  $contactQuery = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/4205b6d80df6ed10';

 // echo $contactQuery;

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $contactQuery);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $XML);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Is the XML I send correct?
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Friends at the end I could solve it:

Do not use double quotes in the value of etag
<entry gd: etag = "SXc8cTVSLyt7I2A9X3JWALgDQgA." .....
In the curl use PUT in "request"
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

I hope you find it useful